# Jquery tablesorter:How to keep sort order on two tables on different html pages, with same headers, but different order and some hidden

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

So I have two html pages, with tables with the same data, although the columns might be in a different order, and some columns will be hidden in one table and not hidden in another. I want the two tables' initial sorts to be based on the other tables sort. Currently I have a script that on sortEnd, creates a 2d array similar to sortList, except instead of indices in the first array, the name of the column is replaced. I then store this array in sessionStoreage so I can access it in the second html page. I am however, unsure how to convert back this array so that column names are changed back to appropriate indices of the second table. I am using the Mottie fork of tablesorter. Below is the first script I made to create the 2d array to send to the other html page.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
    var currentSort;

        $("#myTable").tablesorter({

            widthFixed: false,

            theme: "blue",

            sortReset   : true,


            widgets: ['stickyHeaders'],

            widgetOptions: {
                stickyHeaders_addResizeEvent: true  
            }



  }).bind("sortEnd", function(event) {
      var table = event.target,
      currentSort = table.config.sortList;
      // target the first sorted column
      var columnNum;
      var columnName;
      var currentSortwColumnNames = [[],[]];

      for(var x = 0; x < currentSort.length; x ++)
          {
            if (!currentSort[x]) 
            {                 
                currentSort[x] = [];
            }
            if (!currentSortwColumnNames[x]) 
            {                 
                currentSortwColumnNames[x] = [];
            }


            columnNum = currentSort[x][0];
            columnName = $(table.config.headerList[columnNum]).text();
            currentSortwColumnNames[x][0] = columnName;



            currentSortwColumnNames[x][1] = currentSort[x][1];

          }

      console.log(currentSortwColumnNames.toString());
      sessionStorage.setItem("currentSortwColumnNames",      currentSortwColumnNames);
  })

    } 
); 


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not create an array, but persist the settings as a JSON string:

```
var jsonSettings = JSON.stringify(table.config.sortList);
```

and store this value in the cookie. When needed, just parse it back to an object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonSettings);
```

Comment: The problem, though, is that sortList is a 2d array that holds column index and if its an ascending or descending sort. That's the reason why I created another array, but replaced the column indices with column names instead of indices. I need to do the reverse on the second html page, but am unsure how to go about it. I think I need to use jquery to get an array of column names of headers, and compare that to the currentSortwColumnNames array I stored in sessionStorage.

Comment: so JSON.stringify the array to string, save it to session and JSON.parse it back when needed. It will handle the conversion from string to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`saveSort` widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html) to save and restore the sort on those tables. By default, it saves the sort separately for each table on each page. The trick to get it to work on two tables on different pages is to set the storage options:

- To set session storage, set the [`storage_useSessionStorage`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-storage-use-session-storage) widget option to `true`.

  ```
  $(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({
      widthFixed: false,
      theme: "blue",
      sortReset: true,
      widgets: ['stickyHeaders', 'saveSort'],
      widgetOptions: {
        stickyHeaders_addResizeEvent: true,
        storage_useSessionStorage: true
      }
    });
  });
  ```

  There is no need for the "sortEnd" code now.
- Then set a matching `data-table-page` attribute (any string) on both tables - set by the [`storage_page`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-storage-page) widget option.

  ```
  <table data-table-page="mytable">...</table>
  ```

For more details, see the [`storage` function](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#function-storage) documentation.

Comment: Mottie, that would work, except the columns are in a different order on the two tables (i.e. same column names, but in different order on the table). So when I use that code, the sort order isn't right. That's why in my original code I created that array that was similar to sortList, except I replaced column index with column name (currentSortwColumnNames). What I'm not sure about is how to do the reverse on the second table on the second html page.